# How to print online webpage target element into image programatically?

Tags: python, node.js, printing, jsdom, archiving

Given an online webpage :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1974961
```

Given a target element with `id="REPUTATION"` (here artificially bordered in red) in that webpage :

[image]

**How to print into an image `reputation_1974961.ext` this element ?**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2png

The html2png library lets you pass in an HTML string to its `render` method, and it will render the HTML into a PNG (returned as a buffer in its callback). You should then be able to save the buffer contents to a file using standard file I/O.

As for grabbing the HTML string of just that element: grab the full page with `request` or your request library of choice, then use something like Cheerio to target just the element you want and get its HTML. (Cheerio: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio ).

There may be some gotchas, such as you may need to also grab some styling from the returned HTML and copy that into the rendering string, too, but this should help you find the right direction :)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly using a div id,but I was able to get this much using [imgkit](https://pypi.org/project/imgkit/) and playing around with wkhtmltopdf options. You need to install imgkit and wkhtmltopdf as mentioned in the link.

The crop options given might be different for you so play around with it. You can find all the wkhtmltopdf options  [here](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html).

```
import imgkit
options = {
    'crop-h': '300',
    'crop-w': '400',
    'crop-x': '100',
    'crop-y': '430'
}

imgkit.from_url('https://stackoverflow.com/users/1974961/hugolpz?tab=questions', 'out.jpg',options=options)
```

Output (out.jpg)

[image]

This is not perfect as you can see, but is certainly one of the options you can consider.